# Moq a void method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm trying to work out how this Mock (using the Moq framework) stuff all works, but I've become a bit confused with methods that return void.

The original object has the following methods/properties:

```
void Add(Person entity);
void Save();
IQueryable<Person> Persons;
```

The Add method calls `InsertOnSubmit` (it's Linq to sql), and the Save method calls `Context.SubmitChanges()`. The Person's property returns the `Table<News>` object.

I'm not sure how I go about mocking these methods however, as I obviously can't use `Returns()`.

Or does my design mean that I can't actually Mock the objects properly?

Comment: Without further context it is a little bit difficult to give a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you intend to test.

Moq can help you significantly when you want to test *interactions* between the class being tested and other classes.

In the case you are describing you are presumably testing a class which is using class with methods and properties mentioned above. To verify interactions you want to check if the `Add` method is called with expected parameters, that the `Save` method is called and that the `Persons` property is refered to in order to read results. This can be achieved in the following way:

```
var mockedClass = new Mock<IDaoClass>();
var classUnderTest = ...

mockedClass.SetupGet(m => m.Persons).Returns(new List<Person>().AsQueryable());

classUnderTest.DoSomething();

mockedClass.Verify( m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Person>())); 
mockedClass.Verify( m => m.Save());
```

If you want to test something else and provide a *stub* implementation of these methods then you may want to just create a test implementation or consider using Moq setups with functions expressed as lambdas rather than simple setups.